# Using PM2 to run other npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

In my `package.json` file I have two scripts, `start` and `production`, `start` script is for local development while `production` script is for deployment. Using npm i would just do `npm run production` but how do I do this with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Comment: Mind sharing your `start` script?

Answer (score 7):

I got it, the command is `pm2 start npm --name=app-name -- run production`

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution but I'm always getting the same error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
0|backend- |     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
0|backend- |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)

Comment: @BenjaminD. try `pm2 start npm --name=app -- start`

Comment: It's not working for me. I get an error "Script not found"

Comment: @vijayst can you please ask the pm2 forum, because this has always worked for me and frankly i have no other tricks in my sleeves

Answer (score 0):

Install `pm2` globally using `npm i -g pm2` and then use pm2' command as follow:

`pm2 start npm -- production`

Comment: your command only works for start, in case of production it works with `run production` instead of `production` only

Comment: today i ran my app with :  
**npm run nameScript**  
  ,this shot two service in two ports...  
  
**How can do it with pm2?**